# Can we hide Administrative Time tasks from some users in Project Server?

Tags: 2013, 2016, project-server, ms-project, pwa

I don't want to show Administrative time tasks to some user in project server.

How can we hide it? By default, all user can see set of administrative tasks.

Comment: Do you mean Administrative Time below Time and Task Management in PWA settings

Comment: Yes, I want to disable Administrative task for some user. but it seems global setting, not allowed for person.

Comment: could you please share an image for which link you need to disable it

Comment: http://xyzcom/pwa/_layouts/pwa/Admin/AdmTime.aspx 
here if we add some task, it will be administrative tasks and will be global tasks everyone can see this tasks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In project server with **[Project Permission Mode](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/02/23/sharepoint-permission-mode-vs-project-server-permission-mode-in-project-server-2013/)** enabled, you can control the `PWA setting Links` for a specific user by managing his `Global permission` by doing the following:

- Open PWA Settings.
- Security > Users.
- Global Permissions > Select the Permission you need > Check **Allow** or **Deny**.

But unfortunately, you **can't** manage the permission for a **specific link** because the links have been grouped in main category.

---

So In your case, you need to hide `Administrative Time` below `Time and Task Management` in `PWA Settings` for a specific user.

[image]

So, you should first

- Specify the main category in global permission that holds `Administrative Time` that is **Manage Time Tracking**

[image]

- Check on Deny.
- Go back yo your PWA setting, you will note that `Administrative Time` has been hidden.

[image]

---

**Let's abbreviate the above discussion,**

- You can manage global permission for a specific user to control PWA settings.
- You can't only manage permission for a specific link like `Administrative Time`,Meanwhile you can deny its main category(Group of PWA setting links) `Manage Time Tracking`.
- Deny `Manage Time Tracking` in global permission, will lead to losing other links like

  - Line Classifications
  - Timesheet Settings and Defaults
  - Administrative Time
  - Task Settings and Display
  - Timesheet Managers

Check also my article at [SHAREPOINT PERMISSION MODE VS PROJECT SERVER PERMISSION MODE IN PROJECT SERVER](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/02/23/sharepoint-permission-mode-vs-project-server-permission-mode-in-project-server-2013/)